# Extract signature from keystore in Android Gradle build

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, digital-signature, keystore

I need an approach for extracting the signature from keystore in build procedure. We already this in Java this way:

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = Application.getContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(Application.getContext().getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
for (Signature signature : packageInfo.signatures) {
    byte[] ba = signature.toByteArray());
    // do actions with signatures here ....
}
```

But we don't want this to be done in Java anymore. Instead we need same thing to be run in scope of Gradle build and result of actions are to be written to the BuildConfig constants or to some generated class.

So currently my plan is below:

1. take the signature(the first one) from keystore;
2. run JavaExec to make my actions with signature and return result. Actions are - getting the SHA of this signature and applying Base64
   encoding to the result. Another possible problem which may arise is
   that not all tasks are available in android gradle plugin. So it may
   be possible that I won't be able to run the JavaExec;
3. write the result into one of the BuildConfig constants with the trick like this ["buildConfigField "string", "signatureSHA",
   result"]. And again, not sure that it will work since I don't have an
   idea if the BuildConfig class is generated before or after of any other actions in the build.

How can I retrieve the signature from the keystore in step 1?

Comment: I'm not so into Android or Gradle, but I really don't understand what you mean with "take the signature from (the) keystore". Key stores store keys and certificates, not signatures.

Comment: Hi, by saying "signature" I mean private key. I'm not doing this in gradle anymore. Will use the java for this. javaexec will get a path to keystore file as a parameter(key alias and password too). And there I'll extract the key with java.security.* classes. I'll post results here later, when finish the task

Comment: Where is the promised answer? ;)